# How I position a bootstrap .container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I am trying to position a content DIV on a bootstrap carousel. I tried hardly to figure this out. But still I couldn't.

This is a sreenshot with the output of my current code. But This is not what I want.

[image]

What I want is, this red `DIV` should be position on right side of the carousel. When placing red `DIV`, it should be still in bootstrap `.container` to keep the width of my content properly.

This is my Markup So Far -

```
<div class="banner-content">
  <div id="homepage-feature" class="carousel slide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#homepage-feature" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#homepage-feature" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                 <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
                 <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1500X600">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
                  <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#homepage-feature" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#homepage-feature" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
  </div><!-- /#homepage-feature.carousel -->

  <div class="request-form-holder container"> 
      <div class="request-form">

      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/133/) with my current codding.

My expecting result should be like this -

[image]

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: why not add an id to .item and change the css properties for the id to a background image

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this:

```
.request-form {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/140/

Comment: This is not what I expect. Bootstrap columns are not match with this requirement. Actually I want to position this RED div on the carousel. Clear?

Comment: Your question wasn't clear before, but the picture you added now helps. Check this fiddle while I edit my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/140/

Comment: Sirence, Actually I need to get this Red `div` into a bootstrap container when it positioning above the carousel. Is it possible to do? Thank you.

Comment: Sirence, I want to keep my contents'  alignment properly. Thats why I need to get this red `div` under bootstrap `.container`.  Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/142/ for clear understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what exactly you want anymore. I'd love to help you but right now I'm really confused.

Comment: Sirence, can we have chat regarding this?

Comment: Sure. I found the chat, what room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71873/discussion-between-tnk-and-sirence).

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/137/)

Just added `float:right`

to class *class="request-form"* in CSS.

Is it what you are trying to do>

Comment: No I want this Red div above the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/139/

Replaced in HTML:

- `<div class="request-form"></div>`

Added to css:

- `.addedthisclass {
  position: absolute;
  }`
- and added to css to request-form:

  `.request-form {    float: right;
          margin: 10px 50px 10px auto;
          position: relative;`